# Python Azure Databricks add input- submit button to widgets

Tags: azure-databricks

How can I add a submit button to my widgets and also a listener to the submit button?

[image]

My Python code:

```
dbutils.widgets.removeAll()
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name="inp_type", defaultValue="Please select", choices=["Please select", "IP", "Host"], label="Type:")
dbutils.widgets.text(name="inp_ip_from", defaultValue="none", label="IP From:")
dbutils.widgets.text(name="inp_ip_to", defaultValue="none", label="IP To:")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add submit button and listener to it.

You can configure the behavior of widgets when a new value is selected.

[image]

Click the gear icon at the right end of the Widget panel.

In the pop-up Widget Panel Settings dialog box, choose the widget’s execution behavior.

**Run Notebook:** Every time a new value is selected, the entire notebook is rerun.

**Run Accessed Commands:** Every time a new value is selected, only cells that retrieve the values for that particular widget are rerun. This is the default setting when you create a widget.

**Do Nothing:** Every time a new value is selected, nothing is rerun.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/widgets#configure-widget-settings